# What is the meaning of perl -00 switch? (octal or hexadecimal parameter)

Tags: perl, text-processing, text-parsing

By example, I know that

```
perl -l00e
```

is equivalent to

```
$/ = "\n"; $\ = "\000";
```

it set both `$INPUT` & `$OUTPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR`.

What are other 'tricks' with this switch ?

Comment: `perldoc perlvar`, `$INPUT|$OUTPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR`, it's all very well explained there.

Comment: There's no explanation about `\000` specific trick. It's all about my question

Comment: OK, so not `perdoc perlvar` but `perldoc perlrun`, as you wrote earlier, anyway, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, for `perl -l00e`, `\OOO` is the `null byte`, from `man ascii`

> ```
>      Oct   Dec   Hex   Char                        Oct   Dec   Hex   Char
>      ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
>      000   0     00    NUL '\0' (null character)   100   64    40    @
> ```

So `-l00e` set output separator to `NULL byte`, useful to pipe by example to `xargs -0`

*To go further on a bunch of other 'tricks' :*

`perldoc perlrun`

> -0[octal/hexadecimal]
>   specifies the input record separator ($/ ) as an octal or hexadecimal number. If there are no digits, the null character is the separator. Other switches may precede or follow the digits. For example, if you have a version of find which can print filenames terminated by the null character, you can say this:

```
find . -name '*.orig' -print0 | perl -n0e unlink
```

> The special value 00 will cause Perl to slurp files in paragraph mode. Any value 0400 or above will cause Perl to slurp files whole, but by convention the value 0777 is the one normally used for this purpose.
>
> You can also specify the separator character using hexadecimal notation: -0xHHH..., where the H are valid hexadecimal digits. Unlike the octal form, this one may be used to specify any Unicode character, even those beyond 0xFF. So if you really want a record separator of 0777, specify it as -0x1FF. (This means that you cannot use the -x option with a directory name that consists of hexadecimal digits, or else Perl will think you have specified a hex number to -0.)

Test on all combinations I know are interesting :

```
for i in -l00e -n00e -p00e -n0e -l0e -0ne -0le -p0e -00le -00ne -00pe -0777ne -0777pe -0777le -l0777pe -l0777ne; do
    echo "perl $i"
    perl -MO=Deparse "$i" | head -1 | sed 's|$/|$/ $INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR|;s|$\\|$\\ $OUTPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR|'
done
```

```
perl -l00e
$/ $INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR = "\n"; $\ $OUTPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR = "\000"
perl -n00e
$/ $INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR = ""; $\ $OUTPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR = undef
perl -p00e
$/ $INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR = ""; $\ $OUTPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR = undef
perl -n0e
$/ $INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR = "\000"; $\ $OUTPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR = undef
perl -l0e
$/ $INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR = "\n"; $\ $OUTPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR = "\000"
perl -0ne
$/ $INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR = "\000"; $\ $OUTPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR = undef
perl -0le
$/ $INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR = "\000"; $\ $OUTPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR = "\000"
perl -p0e
$/ $INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR = "\000"; $\ $OUTPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR = undef
perl -00le
$/ $INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR = ""; $\ $OUTPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR = "\n\n"
perl -00ne
$/ $INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR = ""; $\ $OUTPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR = undef
perl -00pe
$/ $INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR = ""; $\ $OUTPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR = undef
perl -0777ne
$/ $INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR = undef; $\ $OUTPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR = undef
perl -0777pe
$/ $INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR = undef; $\ $OUTPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR = undef
perl -0777le
$/ $INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR = undef; $\ $OUTPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR = ""
perl -l0777pe
$/ $INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR = "\n"; $\ $OUTPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR = "\377"
perl -l0777ne
$/ $INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR = "\n"; $\ $OUTPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR = "\377"
```

Comment: OK, but it's a bit of a mess, mixing things up. I suggest to (carefully) read the documentation, to clarify this.

Comment: @wam this got mixed up a bit, `-00` really affects the input record separator, `$/` while your question is about the output record separator, the relevant part of the doc is  `-l[*octnum*]`, not `-0[..]`

Comment: Corrected, thanks @ikegami. If you have other tricks with this octal mode, I will be happy to learn

Comment: Still not sure that this answers your questions as it stands, but now this  is useful

Comment: Modified the question from the post

Comment: If someone knows other interesting tricks like this, feel free to edit or post another answer

Comment: There's at least one more way $/ can be used, but it's not accessible via the switches. See perlvar.